# Proof of von Neumann's Theorem about dense domain

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

The theorem due to von Neumann is the following: if $T$ is a closed densely defined Operator with domain $D(T)$, then also $D(T^*T)$ is also dense.

I am searching for one proof of this non-trivial theorem. Does someone have a link or a book as reference?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're probably looking for that it is even a core, are you?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this:
[image]

Especially, it follows denseness.

Comment: what do you mean with core?

Comment: That looks like a proof I once posted here but was recently removed when a user was removed. I had come up with that proof on my own, and had not seen it done that way before. Did you find it somewhere else? Just curious.

Comment: @LeoraMorita: A core is actually a stronger concept than that of a dense domain. A core is a subdomain such that when closing the restricted operator it will agree with the original one. More precisely, any point within the original domain can be approximated out of the subdomain but in the stronger graph norm. *(I suggest you look it up from a textbook like Kreyszig or you have a look on MSE; let me now if you need help!)*

Comment: @T.A.E.: I found it in Weidmann, Lineare Operatoren in Hilberträumen, Grundlagen, Satz 4.11. *(Its investigations are pretty unique and it's worthwhile to have a look inside.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S : The answer I had for this problem disappeared with the account of Tobias Hurth. It's annoying when answers can be deleted with accounts. I think I like your idea more about posting your own questions and answers, especially if you expect anything to be preserved.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Yes and I think downvoting is ok when I do so. However, sometimes it happens that people start voting to close. I think that is rather critically as it can't be found by search then for example.